# Is it possible to return Cassandra Session object in REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm looking for possible solutions to connect to multiple Cassandra clusters. I tried some solutions presented, but couldn't make them work. So, I have decided to create a microservice to connect to the 2nd cluster. However, I'm trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code for the prepared statements. So, I was thinking, if it's possible to return the session object.

When I try to run this snippet of code, I get Http Status as 415, unsupported media type. Is this the right solution to reduce the duplicate code or what are other options ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class controller {
   private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;
   private CqlTemplate cqlTemplate;
  
   @PostMapping(value="/value")
   public Session returnSession(String query) {
     cqlTemplate = (CqlTemplate) cassandraOperations.getCqlOperations();
     return cqlTemplate.getSessionFactory().getSession();
     
   }
}
```

Comment: First thought : Over the wire , how would you serialize and de-serialize things like connection handles and sessions (never seen this pattern). Even if there was , what happens if an application closes the handle ?

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G Yes, I'm not sure about that too. I need to either connect to multiple clusters in a single microservice or use the 2nd microservice as a bridge to write to the 2nd cluster. This is where I'm very confused and I didn't have success connecting to both clusters in a single microservice.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already seen them, these are some of the implementations I've seen:

- [Spring Boot 2 Cassandra multiple keyspaces or clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123266/)
- [Connect to 2 cassandra clusters in spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635675/)
- https://gist.github.com/mp911de/5da6b66c546f840030ebfd3f8a3ea0e2

For the record, I haven't tried them myself so YMMV. Cheers!